# Nullpointer trying to add textview alertdialog

Tags: android, textview, settext

I'm trying to make an alert dialog with dynamic text. The problem is that the textview I want to edit is in an inflated Layout.
At the topmost of my code is

```
 TextView tv;
```

so I can reach it from all methods in my class. Code snippet below:

```
public class EditNameDialog extends DialogFragment {


    public EditNameDialog() 
        {
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, null);

        this.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog);

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())                
        .setTitle("Skapa profil")
        .setView(textEntryView)
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            }
        }
                )
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
                        new      DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
                    {

                    }
                }
                        ).create();
    }
```

And  the layout file "fragment_dialog.xml" looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/error_dialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/error_connecting"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to edit the TextView, which resides in the "textEntryView". 
To do this i have tried

```
tv = (TextView) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.error_dialog);
```

and then when I call my method:

```
public void attemptLogin(View v) 
{
System.err.println(tv.getText());
}
```

it gives me a Nullpointer.
I don't understand why the id error_dialog cannot be found within the textEntryView View.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you using `tv = (TextView) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.error_dialog); `?

Comment: public void attemptLogin(View v) 
 {
             System.err.println(tv.getText());
        }
in the same class

Comment: I still don't see where you assign a value to `tv`.

Comment: That is purely for debugging purposes, but since I cannot find the "error_dialog" I cannot assign a value to it. I want to do this;
tv.setText("ERROR");

Comment: Try adding `tv = (TextView) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.error_dialog);` after `View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, null);` and running your app.

Comment: I have tried that as well, same error :/

Comment: it is textview or EditText ?

Comment: It is a TextView which i am trying to change the text dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I can not see a declaration for your variable tv, like:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error_dialog);
```

If you have not declarate it, your framework (eclipse?) should give you a hint.
So did you declarate it in an other part of your class?

Comment: I'm sorry, i missed that part.

     TextView tv;

is the first thing in my class.

Comment: Ok, i thought you won't miss it, but sometimes (after hours of writing), these things can happen (especially if you are writing with texteditor).

Comment: where exactly do you get the Nullpointer-Exception? really in your attemptLogin-method, or when trying to get the TextView (tv=....) ? If it it in your method, then your dialog has been found, but the String is set to null (if the error_connecting-String is set correctly, that can not be the case).

Answer (score 0):

your problem is a bit more complicated than it looks. You are losing the reference to your widgets as the View-Object doesn't hold the correct View when you do it like this. I had the same issue and it took me a while figuring it.

I solved it by keeping the View-reference updated and outsourcing the retrieving of the `textView`-value to a later-in-lifecycle-called-method like `onActivityCreated()`

I posted my example that does have an editText and a Button.

**My Example:**

```
public class EnterNumberFragment extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener{

private EditText editText = null;
private Button acceptButton = null;
private View mContentView = null;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflator= getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    mContentView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.dialog_number, null);
    builder.setView(mContentView);

    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onActivityCreated(arg0);
    acceptButton = (Button) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.accept_change);
    editText = (EditText) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.et_number);

    acceptButton.setOnClickListener(this);      
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.accept_change:
            String num = editText.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences sPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PanicPrefs",0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sPrefs.edit();
            prefEditor.putString("NumberToCall", num).commit();
            dismiss();
            break;

         default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem exist in this line:-

```
  LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
```

you don't have a reference of activity. What you can do is to pass an activity context and then get the activity:-

LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(mContext.getActivity());

or you can use following code:-

```
LayoutInflater factory = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```